# How to get last inserted id in SQL Server 2000 using ODBC?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sql-server-2000, lastinsertid, last-insert-id

I'm using this code to insert new record to database:

```
function newProtocol($date, $type, $text, $who, $reff) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO c_rozhovor (ref_kunde, protokol_typ, besuch_protokol, datum_vzniku, kto_vytvoril) VALUES ('"
            .msescape($reff)."','"
            .msescape($type)."','"
            .msescape($text)."','"
            .msescape($date)."','"
            .msescape($who)."')";

    $connection = odbc_connect(constant('DATABASE_NAME'),'','');
    if (!connection) return false;      

    $query = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
    if (!query) return false;

    return "New protocol was successfuly saved!";   
}
```

I would like somehow to return **last inserted id** instead of `New protocol was successfully saved!` string. Something like `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in MySql. Is there a way to achieve that in SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the following modification of your code:

```
function newProtocol($date, $type, $text, $who, $reff) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO c_rozhovor (ref_kunde, protokol_typ, besuch_protokol, datum_vzniku, kto_vytvoril) VALUES ('"
            .msescape($reff)."','"
            .msescape($type)."','"
            .msescape($text)."','"
            .msescape($date)."','"
            .msescape($who)."') SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

    $connection = odbc_connect(constant('DATABASE_NAME'),'','');
    if (!connection) return false;      

    $query = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
    if (!query) return false;

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This returns error "undefinde function IDENT_CURENT..."

Comment: Yes, you can make a query to that and capture the returned value.
see the edited answer.

Comment: the same as before: undefined function Ident_current().."

Comment: Can you try the edited answer and tell me what is your output.